# Use of ~라 as a sentence ender to give a warning

Tags: grammar, meaning

This is related to the question [here](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/korean-sentence-ending-that-implies-be-careful-x-might-happen)

The [answer posted by Gaeguri](https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/1689/91) seems to be what I was looking for, but I wanted some more information, and found this dictionary definition

[image]

Transcript:

라
1. 서술적

게으름 피우다간 낙제할~ If you are idle, you will flunk, I warn you

그는 아직 어린애~ 그 말을 이해할 수 없다 He is too young to understand it

그는 내 아들이 아니~ 내 조카다 He is not my son, but my nephew

Only sentence 1 seems to have the sense as explained by Gaeguri in the answer to the other question (and it sounds like something an adult would say to the child) but the other examples don't seem to have the same usage of 라

How is the usage of ~라 as used in the first sentence similar (or related) to it's usage in the other sentences?

Also, what does 서술적 mean?

Comment: What dictionary is that from?

Comment: just a mobile app

Comment: Might it be worth a link to the app as a reference? (and in case anyone else is interested in the app!)

Comment: It came preinstalled so I don't know if it is downloadable or not

Answer (score 4):

I believe your dictionary made a mistake.  Sentence 1 is using ending -ㄹ라 (which is in [the previous answer you linked to](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/korean-sentence-ending-that-implies-be-careful-x-might-happen/1689#1689)); the other two are using ending -라.

Naver dictionary entries for: [-ㄹ라](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=11423400) / [-라 (connecting)](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=11439000) / [-라 (imperative)](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=11439200)